# Do you need to set an encryption key before using nvme-cli cryptographic erase or cryptographic sanitize?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssd, encryption, nvme

[nvme-cli](https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli) has both a [`format`](https://www.mankier.com/1/nvme-format) and [`sanitize`](https://review.spdk.io/gerrit/plugins/gitiles/spdk/nvme-cli/+/1ba85e5bb5ba3446228d6cbb4eb9f92a28aedf6b/Documentation/nvme-sanitize.txt) command that can be used to securely erase an NVMe SSD. Both of these commands offer a cryptographic approach, where the drive's encryption key is changed/deleted, making the data inaccessible.

***Sanitize device /dev/nvme0n1 using Crypto Erase sanitize operation***

```
nvme sanitize /dev/nvme0n1 -a 4
```

***Securely erase /dev/nvme0n1 via Cryptigraphic erase***

```
nvme format /dev/nvme0n1 -s 2
```

Questions:

1. Do you need to explicitly set a password/encryption key prior to issuing either of these commands. If so, how?
2. How to verify the encryption key has been set prior to issuing the command, and verify it's been successfully removed, after the command has completed?

Comment: Try it and find out?

Comment: I'm not certain how to set an encryption key for a drive in Linux (that was one of the reasons I posted the question.) I'm assuming it needs to be set - how is this typically done?

Comment: Not being familiar with `nvme` or SSDs I couldn't rightly advise you. But unless you specifically encrypt partitions, I'd expect it's done at a firmware level and not generally accessible in userspace. What does `man nvme` reveal?

Comment: I was looking at `man nvme` earlier, but I couldn't find anything related to encryption or setting a password. I know with `hdparam` for doing secure erase on ATA drives, there's an option for setting the encryption key (`--security-set-pass`), which is why I thought maybe nvme-cli would have something similar, but I am unable to find it. Makes sense that it would be done at the firmware level, thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: Oh wait, I wonder if this might be useful. `nvme security-send` https://www.mankier.com/1/nvme-security-send

Comment: For anyone curious who stumbles upon this, I found this question about cryptographic erase posted on the nvme-cli github page. It expands a little bit on the issue. https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli/issues/1107  This page indicates that the way cryptographic erase occurs is vendor specific, so maybe the effect can't be entirely predicted. I'm still uncertain how one would enable security / set an encryption key, or if this can be done via nvme-cli, but I hope this link provides some useful info for understanding the  cryptographic erase commands better.